# Overloading >> operator and reading char

Tags: c++

I'm having some trouble overloading the `>>` operator and can't seem to find a correct way to do it.

I'm supposed to be opening a file, reading a character, and the changing a variable of an object based on the character.

Here is my function:

```
istream &operator >> (istream &strm, RNode &obj) {
    char tempChar = nullptr;

    strm >> tempChar;

    if (tempChar == '#') {
        obj.setReservationStatus(true);
    } else {
        obj.setReservationStatus(false);
    }
    return strm;
}
```

and here is what I am trying to test it with. We're making a movie reservation system, so `#` are empty seats, and `.` are reserved seats. The idea is to check which character it is, then change `reservationStatus`.

```
fs.open("auditorium1.txt", ios::in);

RNode *tempNode;
fs >> tempNode;

cout << tempNode.getReservationStatus();
```

I get an error that says "No match for 'operator>>'" and it gives me a bunch of data types I could use and the reasons why I can't.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can't use a pointer, i.e. `RNode *` with `operator>>`. Change `RNode *tempNode;` to `RNode tempNode;`.

Comment: Check the parameter type of `operator >>`, which expects a `RNode`, not a `RNode*`. BTW: `operator >>` alo can't be declared to take a pointer as parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RNode *tempNode;
fs >> tempNode;
```

is not right. A pointer cannot be used when the function expects a reference to an object. You should get a compiler error on that line. It should be

```
RNode tempNode;
fs >> tempNode;
```

Also, in the `operator>>` function,

```
char tempChar = nullptr;
```

is not right. `nullptr` should be used initialize pointers, not a `char`.

You can simplify the function to:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &strm, RNode &obj) {

    char tempChar;

    strm >> tempChar;

    obj.setReservationStatus(tempChar == '#');

    return strm;
}
```